# Remove / add classes between elements according to multiple select boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a comparison table that uses multiple select boxes to pick the products to display in the table. To prevent duplication, I have a jQuery code that switches between the select boxes if a duplicate product is selected.

By default all divs that contain the products are set to `display: none;`

I wish to move the display classes: compare-col-1, compare-col-2, compare-col-3
between the divs to make them display according to the selected option in all select boxes.

Here is the CSS code:

```
.product-col {
  display: none;
}

.compare-col-1 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  order: 1;
  display: block;
}

.compare-col-2 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
  -webkit-order: 2;
  -ms-flex-order: 2;
  order: 2;
  display: block;
}

.compare-col-3 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 4;
  -webkit-order: 3;
  -ms-flex-order: 3;
  order: 3;
  display: block;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="container p-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <select class="custom-select product-selector">
        <option value="product1" selected>Product 1</option>
        <option value="product2">Product 2</option>
        <option value="product3">Product 3</option>
        <option value="product4">Product 4</option>
        <option value="product5">Product 5</option>
        <option value="product6">Product 6</option>
        <option value="product7">Product 7</option>
        <option value="product8">Product 8</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <select class="custom-select product-selector">
        <option value="product1">Product 1</option>
        <option value="product2" selected>Product 2</option>
        <option value="product3">Product 3</option>
        <option value="product4">Product 4</option>
        <option value="product5">Product 5</option>
        <option value="product6">Product 6</option>
        <option value="product7">Product 7</option>
        <option value="product8">Product 8</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <select class="custom-select product-selector">
        <option value="product1">Product 1</option>
        <option value="product2">Product 2</option>
        <option value="product3" selected>Product 3</option>
        <option value="product4">Product 4</option>
        <option value="product5">Product 5</option>
        <option value="product6">Product 6</option>
        <option value="product7">Product 7</option>
        <option value="product8">Product 8</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
        <div id="product1" class="product-col col text-center compare-col-1">This is Product 1</div>
        <div id="product2" class="product-col col text-center compare-col-2">This is Product 2</div>
        <div id="product3" class="product-col col text-center compare-col-3">This is Product 3</div>
        <div id="product4" class="product-col col text-center">This is Product 4</div>
        <div id="product5" class="product-col col text-center">This is Product 5</div>
        <div id="product6" class="product-col col text-center">This is Product 6</div>
        <div id="product7" class="product-col col text-center">This is Product 7</div>
        <div id="product8" class="product-col col text-center">This is Product 8</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery code to create the switch between select boxes:

```
$(".product-selector").each(function(){
    $(this).data('__old', this.value);
}).change(function() {
    var $this = $(this), value = $this.val(), oldValue = $this.data('__old');

    $(".product-selector").not(this).filter(function(){
        return this.value == value;
    }).val(oldValue).data('__old', oldValue);

    $this.data('__old', value)
});
```

Here is a CodePen with the code: https://codepen.io/Cybergoat/pen/XzdZRa

I haven't found a solution to my problem yet and any direction would very much be appreciated.

Comment: you should add either a class or an id to your selects to identify the col in the change function, such as `product-selector_1`, _2 etc. This way you will be able to know which class to add to the selected product for it to appear at the good place

Comment: Hello, can you make a simple scenario and the expected output ?

Comment: @Cylexx I wish to replicate the functionality from [Apple's site](https://www.apple.com/iphone/compare/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how you can do it: as i said in my comment, adding an id can make it possible to identify the column to which display the wanted row:

**NOTE:** your system for placing elements seems to not work universally (it doesn't in the present SO snippet), but you can see the classes are added well in [the codepen modified from yours](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ooLojm)

```js
$(".product-selector").each(function(){
    $(this).data('__old', this.value);
}).change(function() {
    var $this = $(this), value = $this.val(), oldValue = $this.data('__old'), col, dupe, dupeCol;
    
    dupe = $(".product-selector").not(this).filter(function(){
        return this.value == value;
    });
    if(dupe.length){
        dupe.val(oldValue).data('__old', oldValue);
        //identify the col
        dupeCol = dupe.attr('id').replace('product-col-', '');
        //remove class from old element
        $(".product-col").removeClass('compare-col-' + dupeCol);
        //set it to the new one
        $("#" + oldValue).addClass('compare-col-' + dupeCol);
    }
    
    //identify the col
    col = $this.attr('id').replace('product-col-', '')
    //remove class from old element
    $(".product-col").removeClass('compare-col-' + col);
    //set it to the new one
    $("#" + value).addClass('compare-col-' + col);
    
    $this.data('__old', value);
});
```

```css
.product-col {
  display: none;
}

.compare-col-1 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
  -webkit-order: 1;
  -ms-flex-order: 1;
  order: 1;
  display: block;
}

.compare-col-2 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 3;
  -webkit-order: 2;
  -ms-flex-order: 2;
  order: 2;
  display: block;
}

.compare-col-3 {
  -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 4;
  -webkit-order: 3;
  -ms-flex-order: 3;
  order: 3;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container p-4">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col text-center">
      <select id="product-col-1" class="custom-select product-selector">
        <option value="product1" selected>Product 1</option>
        <option value="product2">Product 2</option>
        <option value="product3">Product 3</option>
        <option value="product4">Product 4</option>
        <option value="product5">Product 5</option>
        <option value="product6">Product 6</option>
        <option value="product7">Product 7</option>
        <option value="product8">Product 8</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <select id="product-col-2" class="custom-select product-selector">
        <option value="product1">Product 1</option>
        <option value="product2" selected>Product 2</option>
        <option value="product3">Product 3</option>
        <option value="product4">Product 4</option>
        <option value="product5">Product 5</option>
        <option value="product6">Product 6</option>
        <option value="product7">Product 7</option>
        <option value="product8">Product 8</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col text-center">
      <select id="product-col-3" class="custom-select product-selector">
        <option value="product1">Product 1</option>
        <option value="product2">Product 2</option>
        <option value="product3" selected>Product 3</option>
        <option value="product4">Product 4</option>
        <option value="product5">Product 5</option>
        <option value="product6">Product 6</option>
        <option value="product7">Product 7</option>
        <option value="product8">Product 8</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
      <div id="product1" class="product-col col text-center compare-col-1">This is Product 1</div>
      <div id="product2" class="product-col col text-center compare-col-2">This is Product 2</div>
      <div id="product3" class="product-col col text-center compare-col-3">This is Product 3</div>
      <div id="product4" class="product-col col text-center">This is Product 4</div>
      <div id="product5" class="product-col col text-center">This is Product 5</div>
      <div id="product6" class="product-col col text-center">This is Product 6</div>
      <div id="product7" class="product-col col text-center">This is Product 7</div>
      <div id="product8" class="product-col col text-center">This is Product 8</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```